# Accessing RDS from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

**RDS Database details:**

I have an publicly accessible RDS database which is restricted to be accessible to only specific IP address.

The RDS have 2 security groups attached to the RDS:

- 1st security group allows a specific IP address to access it.
- 2nd security group allows multiple specific IP addresses to access
  it.

Note: I know I can just keep a single security group for this purpose.

This RDS database have the default VPC and 3 public subnets. All these subnets have 2 routes in route tables:

- Destination: default vpc's cidr range and Target: local
- Destination: 0.0.0.0/0 and Target: internet gateway

**Lambda function details:**

I have a lambda function, which does not have any vpc configured.

I am trying to access the RDS database from code in the lambda function. Since lambda doesn't have any specific IP address, I couldn't add inbound rule in RDS's security group to allow it. When I simply add inbound rule in RDS's security group to allow access from all IPs then my lambda function code is able to connect to RDS database and work with it.

I wouldn't want my RDS database to be allowed access from anywhere on the internet, what configuration/settings do I need to make to be able to access RDS from lambda.

I also tried configuring the lambda function to be in same vpc and same subnets as that of for RDS instance; but I haven't been successful in making a connection to the RDS database.

Comment: Please share security group settings of Lambda and RDS. And what RDS type you are using for more information.

Comment: Since the lambda is not configured for any vpc, there are no security groups. At least that's what I am seeing, please let me know if you think I am missing anything here.

RDS has 2 security groups:
1st SG: Inbound rule: homeprivateip allowing port 3306 (mysqlaurora database) and outbound rule allowing all traffic on all ports.
2nd SG: Inbound rule: officeprivateip allowing port 3306 (mysqlaurora database) and outbound rule allowing all traffic on all ports.

Comment: If your RDS is not internet accesible and your lambda is not in the same VPC as RDS it is impossible for the lambda to have access to the RDS instance.

Comment: My RDS is internet accessible, I mentioned in my question that my RDS is publicly accessible and I am restricting access to the RDS using the security groups rules.

Comment: Then what exactly is your question? Do you want to use VPC or not? Do you want your lambda to go over the internet to your RDS instance and pay for outbound and inbound traffic? Pay for elastic IP,.....?

Comment: Thanks for trying help me out @Lucasz. 
I cannot change the RDS instance to make it non-public. I only have to restrict access to it using security groups. For my home ip, I added my ip in inbound rule of RDS SG and I can access RDS from my laptop; but for lambda there is no such ip address that I can put in there to allow lambda to access my RDS.
What settings do I need to make to lambda's VPC/SG etc or anywhere else in order to make the lambda be able to access RDS, as of now the lambda is not configured of any VPC. Let me know if any questions please.

Comment: You can put the lambda in a VPC add a nat gateway to it and then it will have a IP address which it is able to use to connect to the internet. You can allow that IP from the nat gateway to connect to the RDS instance. But I would never configure this like that. Can you please read my answer and follow the steps to assign the vpc to the lambda.

Comment: Thanks @Lucasz. I would look into what you suggested in answer. I already gone through that link in your answer before but now I feel that I might have missed something somewhere.

Comment: @Lucasz I tried this and I yet haven't been successful. I have default vpc with 3 subnets all are public subnets attached to my lambda function as well as same are for  my rds instance. Shouldn't the communication happen in this case?

I am not very good at the vpc section yet, do aws allows connections in between public subnets in the default vpc? Sorry if it's very basic question, I am like newbie in vpc section.

Comment: Please read the section of security groups. You have to assign a securitygroup.to the RDS that allows access to and from the lambda. You have to assign another security group to the lambda that allows access to and from the RDS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best in this case is to use the same VPC for your lambda as the RDS instance. This is cheaper and is more secure. You don't have to setup a internet gateway and elastic IP. And you can only access your RDS instance from within the VPC.

You can enable this using Lambda management console. Select Lambda function which need access to RDS instance and then go to Configuration -> Advanced settings and select the VPC (which is your RDS instance is in) you need it to access.

For instances attached to the same security group—make the security group the source for the inbound rule and the destination for the outbound rule.

For instances in different security groups—make sure that both security groups allow access to one another.

If this is still not working check the error message that is returned when setting up the connection with RDS. Timeout means issue with network.

find out more here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-lambda-to-an-rds-instance/

Comment: Thanks @Lucasz for your response. When you say instances attached to same security group, you mean rds instance and lambda function (I am not working with any ec2 instances here).
BTW, before posting this question, I tried a lot of things (also already tried what is mentioned in https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-lambda-to-an-rds-instance/ before posting this question) and went through many answers; but haven't been successful though.

Comment: If you want to not use internet accesible RDS you have to setup your lambda in the same VPC as your RDS. Then allow traffic from each of the security group or place them in the same security group as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Placing them in the same security group still requires a rule specifically allowing that traffic in the security group. Placing things like this in the same security group is generally a bad idea because the different services now have ports open that make no sense for those services. It's much better to create a separate security group for each type of service.